# Package pgfkeys Error

Tags: errors, pgfkeys

With example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[\@photoshape, draw=\@photoborder, line width=0.3mm, inner sep=\photodim, fill overzoom image = \@photo ] () {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get the error

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/fill overzoom image' and I am going to ignore it.

 Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

Comment: https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/issues/178

Comment: Does it work with an updated TeX distribution?